# HTML5 Clipboard API: paste custom format

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, clipboarddata

We are using a 3D CAD application which allows to copy the 3D data in a special format to the clipboard. We now want to paste this 3D data (basically it's structured as XML) in the browser.

I tried a lot with the HTML5 Clipboard API, but besides text and HTML nothing works, the `clipboardData` is always emtpy...

Even if I log the type, besides text and HTML, it's empty:
`console.log(event.clipboardData.types);`

Retrieving data with `event.clipboardData.getData('application/x-egr-eai-basket-cutbuffer-uncompressed')` doesn't work, too.

Is it even possible to paste such a custom format in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems custom data formats for the clipboard are not directly supported. According to the specification in [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#writing-contents-to-the-clipboard):

If data type is text/plain:

1. Ensure encoding is correct per OS and locale conventions
2. Normalize line endings according to platform conventions
3. Place text on clipboard with the appropriate OS clipboard format description

**Otherwise, if data is of a type listed in the mandatory data types list**

Place part on clipboard with the appropriate OS clipboard format description

**Otherwise**

This is left to the implementation..

This suggests to me that any custom types will be ignored by browsers.
As such, I'd advise simply saving the XML as a string to the clipboard and retrieving it using `event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')`

Comment: Yeah, I was reading the same specification and already feared that it is like it is. Using `text/plain` isn't working, maybe because of the way the 3D applications puts the contents into the clipboard (not as text). But thanks anyway, now it seems clearer to me.

Comment: @AndreasRemdt. Maybe log this as an issue on the 3D application's forum. It may be a common issue with that application, and they may have workarounds.